# What Facebook API call results in this? The result shows a publish dialog

Tags: graph, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've asked this before, but in a different way, so I'm hoping asking it like this could get an answer :)

What API call results in this following dialog appearing:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/222489/publishdialog.png

By using the FB.ui({method: 'stream.publish' ... function all I get is a "Post to Your Wall" dialog, and all great Facebook games get the dialog in the screenshot. So I must be using the wrong function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand how you've missed it, it's the first snippet of code in the [FB.ui](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/fb.ui/) documentation:

```
FB.ui(
   {
     method: 'feed',
     name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
     link: 'http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
     picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
     caption: 'Reference Documentation',
     description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.',
     message: 'Facebook Dialogs are easy!'
   },
   function(response) {
     if (response && response.post_id) {
       alert('Post was published.');
     } else {
       alert('Post was not published.');
     }
   }
);
```

Result in my test app:
[image]

Comment: See but that is just the dialog I don't want to appear, as I stated in my question, I want to get the other dialog as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: @Nixarn, huh? this is the same dialog as in the screenshot attached in your question...am I missing something here?

Comment: @ifavour yeah two things, that's why I'm thinking it could be some other dialog. First of the title in my screenshot says ""Publish this story to your Facebook Wall and your friends' home pages?" secondly, the message is gray colored in the one I showed (even using user_message_prompt I can't get it to be gray)

Comment: Ah I see, it seems that they are using the `fbml.dialog` method with the attribute `fbml` this will let them use something like [`fb:header`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/header) or [`fb:dialog-title`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/dialog-title/), but this is not a good practice as facebook is in the process of deprecating the FBML anyway!

Comment: You can view the source of the app and get the JS code that is producing that dialog I suppose!

Comment: Hmm true, yeah, it seems like this other dialog is some old code. I just checked Zynga's new CityVille and it uses this new dialog. I was just worried I was using some wrong dialog that wouldn't get as much attention.

Comment: Yeah, just stick with the latest APIs updates as FB is keeping on changing things! and you don't want your App to break!

Answer (score 1):

Its known as a Feed Dialogue.. its one of the Three Facebook Dialogues that use user interaction for doing some work...
ItI dosent need a API call (It was possible with `Facebook.showFeedDialog` but now facebook dosent support it) instead u redirect the user to the Url for these dialogues.

`http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?<your different attributes as quesry string>`

For having this in your own page you Can open it in an `iFrame`by setting attribute `display=iframe` but you need an access token for that..

Here is a complete description..

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/