# Facebook standard status update popup?

Tags: facebook

Is there an API for opening a popup containing the same status update functionality as in the Facebook Wall?

I basically want to open the following UI in a popup...

[image: Facebook Status Update]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You have to mention the onclick function else what suits your need. oauth2 in facebook involves two steps, call authorize to get code, then call access_token to get token. One way to deal with the pop login:

open login url in new window just like you did,when the facebook redirects back to your url in the popup, you set the cookie either through server side code or using javascript to capture url query parameter, when page is loaded in the popup, close the window immediately window.close.

On your main page, after your window.open code, add JavaScript code to detect if popup is closed and capture the cookie:

var signinWin;

```
`$('#FacebookBtn').click(function () {
        var pos = screenCenterPos(800, 500);
        signinWin = window.open("[URL]", "SignIn", "width=780,height=410,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0,resizable=0,location=0,menuBar=0,left=" + pos.x + ",top=" + pos.y);
        setTimeout(CheckLoginStatus, 2000);
        signinWin.focus();
        return false;
    });

function CheckLoginStatus() {
    if (signinWin.closed) {
        $('#UserInfo').text($.cookie("some_cookie");
    }
    else setTimeout(CheckLoginStatus, 1000);
}`
```

hope it help you.

Comment: The thing is I am not interested in a login-popup. I want the share method that is used in the wall instead of implementing it myself in my application. (See screenshot in my original question)

Answer (score 1):

The facebook UI responsible to post a feed is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658957/what-facebook-api-call-results-in-this-the-result-shows-a-publish-dialog/4660424#4660424).

If you want to have the same design in your application you have to design it yourself, which would be easy with jQuery + ajax

Comment: Ok, so I can at least have the user share status messages and an image I define. I read the user's photos, videos and status messages based on tags in the feed and would like them to be able to upload videos, images and status messages easily from the application without involving a local storage on my server. But I guess there's no official support for that?

Comment: While SDKs and FB.UI make it easy for you but I suppose you have to build these features yourself or do a research to check if any already exists.